# Rails 4: Complicated helper tag for video

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tags

I am using a video slider in my website and the plugin requires the format to be the following:

```
<li class="slide" data-mightyslider="
    cover:'path_to_cover',
    title: 'title_name'">
</li>
```

I want to replace "path_to_cover" with `<%= image_tag "image_name" %>` but I cannot seem to get it to work with `content_tag`.  How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image_tag` helper isn't what you want in this instance.

Try this:

```
<%= content_tag :li, class: "slide", data: { mightyslider: raw("cover: '#{image_path('something.jpg')}', title: 'title_name'") } do %>
  list item content
<% end %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  I'm glad I asked because that would've taken a long time to figure out!